# Why can't I delete a post I made?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I posted a question a couple years ago. It did not receive any answers for several days, at which point I decided to do my own research for a second time to see if I missed something, and found the answer to it, so I answered my own question. Since then, the only activity on the post has been a lot of downvotes (not entirely sure why it keeps getting downvoted, but I don't really care), which keep costing me reputation. I tried to delete the post because after several updates to the game, it is now outdated. It wouldn't let me delete it, instead it asked if I wanted to recommend a community vote to delete it. I tried deleting the answer, too, with the same results. Any idea why this happened?

Comment: What is the question in question here? There are a number of conditions that could prevent self deletion of a question, so it would help to find out exactly which one you mean

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/299952/172464

Comment: Hmm... I see two deleted answers, which is my best guess, but they're both negatively scored so that doesn't 100% make sense either

Comment: @Unionhawk i see a non-deleted, downvoted answer which has been accepted. doesn't the accepted answer prevent deleting?

Comment: @Memor-X That's the self-answer which I would assume (perhaps incorrectly) to be not considered in any question deletion calculation

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, based on [Memor-X's comment](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13195/why-cant-i-delete-a-post-i-made#comment41757_13195), because you have accepted an answer.

> i see a non-deleted, downvoted answer which has been accepted. doesn't the accepted answer prevent deleting?

From the FAQ, [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222)

> ## When *can't* I delete my own post?
>
> **Special note:** You can't delete your own post using the iOS or Android apps. You can, however, delete your post by using the app's option to open the question in a Web browser and deleting it from there, provided none of the below apply.
>
> You can't delete your own *answer* if it has been [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about).
>
> You can't delete your own *question* if it:
>
> - has an [answer with upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)
> - has an accepted answer
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
> - [has an answer with an awarded bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele?cb=1)
>
> You can't delete *any* of your questions or answers if you haven't *registered* your account (that is, associated a Google, Facebook, or Stack Exchange account with it).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I unaccepted the answer, but it did get up votes at one point I think, so that might be the issue.